# Sum function didn't work javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have problem to sum text-box , but the text box can appeared if only i press add more button . so i mix it with on click function and the result is a **sum function only can sum the first text box .**

Here's my javascript :

```
var i = $('table tr').length;
var count = $('table tr').length;
var row = i;
var a = 0;

for (a = 0; a <= i; a++) {
  $(".addmore_" + a).on('click', function (a) {
    return function() {
    var box = $("#box_"+ a);
    box.val( Number(box.val())+1 );

      var data = "<td><input class='form-control sedang' type='text' id='packinglist_" + a + "' name='packinglist"+ a +"[]'/></td>";
      $("#keatas_" + a).append(data);

    $("#packinglist_"+ a).each(function() {

            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });


    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $("#packinglist_"+ a).each(function() {

            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#netto_"+ a).val(sum.toFixed(2));



                        };

            }
    }(a));

}
```

Here my html which mixed with php :

```
for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['jumlahdata'];$i++)
            {
                    $nomor = $a[0];
                    $iden = $nomor + $i;
                        echo"   <tr>
                                <td><span id='snum'>$i.</span></td>
                                <input class='form-control' type='hidden' id='hiddenlot_$i' name='hiddenlot[]' />
                                <input class='form-control' type='hidden' id='hiddencustomer_$i' name='hiddencustomer[]' />
                                <input class='form-control' type='hidden' id='hiddenprice_$i' name='hiddenprice[]' />
                                <td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='jenisbenang_$i' name='jenisbenang[]' readonly/></td>
                                <td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='warna_$i' name='warna[]' readonly/></td>                                
                                <td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='lot_$i' name='lot[]' required/></td>
                                <td><input class='form-control sedang' type='text' id='netto_$i' name='netto[]' required/> </td>
                                <td><input class='form-control pendek' type='text' id='box_$i' name='box[]' /> </td>
                                <td><input class='form-control pendek' type='text' id='cones_$i' name='cones[]'/> </td>
                                <td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='keterangan_$i' name='keterangan[]'/>
                                <input class='form-control' type='hidden' id='keterangan_$i' name='identitas[]' value='$iden'/>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td><a><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus addmore_$i' id='$i'></span></a><br>
                                <a><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus delete_$i'></a> </td>
                            <td colspan='10'>
                                <table id='keatas_$i' class='keatas'>
                                <tr>

                                </tr>   
                                </table>
                            </tr>
                            </td>";

            }
```

any response would be appreciated , thanks

**[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jeremyjemy/c0bq902t/2/)**

Comment: Can you provide the rendered HTML pls

Comment: why are you binding `event` inside an `event`. In your current code multiple event bind performs.

Comment: On a first loop you are calling `calculateSum();`  at that time only one `input` added.

Comment: You have to do event binding `$(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });` outside `each`.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi but when i put   `$("#packinglist_"+ a).each(function() {

            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();` outside loop it cant read `var a`

Comment: @AdamJeffers how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is applying keyup event listener inside click callback. For every click on ".addMore_"+a element, you are appending a `<td>` with id "packinglist_"+a in the a^th row. After that you are attaching keyup listener on that element. you are selecting with id which returns only the first match not all. so its only attaching listener to first `<td>` in that row with the id. Correction is given in code.

Alternatively you can do this using class. But you need to be careful to not attach events multiple times to an element.This causes unexpected behaviour and sometimes browser crashes.

in calculateSum function also you are accessing element by id which returns only one element. This should be fixed by giving unique class for input boxes of each row.

```
 var i = $('table tr').length;
 var count = $('table tr').length;
 var row = i;
 var a = 0;

for (a = 0; a <= i; a++) {
  $(".addmore_" + a).on('click',function () {
  return function() {
  var box = $("#box_"+ a);
  box.val( Number(box.val())+1 );

  var rowIdentifier="packinglist_" + a;
  var data = $("<td><input class='form-control sedang "+rowIdentifier +"' type='text' id='packinglist_" + a + "' name='packinglist"+ a +"[]'/></td>");

  $("#keatas_" + a).append(data);

data.find('input').on('keyup',function(){
            calculateSum();
        });

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".packinglist_"+ a).each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#netto_"+ a).val(sum.toFixed(2));
                    };
        }
}(a));
}
```

Let me know if this helps. Try to simplify the html structure. its difficult to understand.

https://jsfiddle.net/rishabdev919/mj3gsLxe/
See the working fiddle

Comment: thanks for helping , but i was try and now the input box didnt appear

Comment: pls check my jsfiddle if you want live demo

Comment: It's an IIFE that returns the actual event handler while keeping `a` in a closure, locking its value so it's unaffected by the loop.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Can you explain what are you talking about. Inside an handler you always get the incorrect value since handler is called after loop has executed. Can you show with a fiddle in this case if the click handler gets the correct value.

Comment: `function(a) { return function() { /* stuff that uses a */ }; }(a)` is a closure that returns the actual event handler.

Comment: Thanks for enlightenment. Changed the answer. @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: @JeremyHermawan I have solved the problem according to your code structure. Please go through it and the fiddle. There are various ways to do it but if you could see the mistakes in your code then you learn something and automatically apply best practices with experience.

Comment: but i still didnt understand your code , i hope i find someone who want teach me lol

Comment: i didnt get it `{'index':a}`  , and it can work cause you change `$("#packinglist_"+a).each` into `data.each` , am i right?

Comment: {'index':a} was not required.. see the updated code and comments above. I changed $("#packinglist_"+a) to data.each because you only need to attach listener to currently generated input box only. so data is jquery object of currently generated <td>. $("#packinglist_"+a) wont work because when you have multiple elements with with same id then jquery returns the first matching element. thats why keyup on subsequent inputs was not working. Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98479/discussion-between-rishabh-dev-and-jeremy-hermawan).

Answer (score 1):

Please don't define click event and function inside a loop, try to use global classes so you don't need to use loop, check my suggestion bellow.

**NOTE :** You should use `$('body').on('keyup','.packinglist', function(){` since `$('.packinglist').keyup( function(){` can't deal with fresh DOM added by the script.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('body').on('click', ".add-btn", function () {
    var parent_tr= $(this).closest('tr');
    var index= parent_tr.data('index');

    var box = parent_tr.find('input[name="box[]"]');
    box.val( Number(box.val())+1 );

    var data = "<td><input class='packinglist form-control sedang' type='text' id='packinglist_" + index + "' name='packinglist"+ index +"[]'/></td>";
    
    $("#keatas_" + index).append(data);
});

$('body').on('keyup','.packinglist', function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
    
   var parent_tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var sum = 0;
    
    parent_tr.find('.packinglist').each(function() {
      if(!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val().length!=0) {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
      }
    });
    
    parent_tr.prev('tr').find('input[name="netto[]"]').val(sum.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class='form-control sedang' type='text' id='netto_1' name='netto[]' placeholder="netto" required/> </td>
  <tr data-index='1'>
    <td><a><input type='button' value='addmore' class='add-btn glyphicon glyphicon-plus addmore_1'><br> </td>
    <td colspan='10'>
      <table id='keatas_1' class='keatas'>
        <tr>

        </tr> 
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input class='form-control sedang' type='text' id='netto_2' name='netto[]' placeholder="netto" required/> </td>
  <tr data-index='2'>
    <td><a><input type='button' value='addmore' class='add-btn glyphicon glyphicon-plus addmore_2'><br> </td>
    <td colspan='10'>
      <table id='keatas_2' class='keatas'>
        <tr>

        </tr> 
      </table>
      </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so i need change   $(".addmore_" + a).on('click', function (a) { with $('.global_class').on('click', function (a) { ?

Comment: @JeremyHermawan check my suggestion in snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `keyup` event binding out side loop

```
 $("#packinglist_"+ a).each(function() {

            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });
```

Add a class `.packageList` and bind `keyup` with class.

```
$("tr").on("keyup", ".packageList", function(evt) {
       calculateSum();
});
```

Comment: if i bring it outside the loop how can i define var a ?

Comment: you don't have to track with `id` for that i have made it simpler with `class`. Please add class.

Comment: Also you can do this for `AddMore` click.

Comment: note : i have table in table , should i use parents function?

Comment: Ok so do this for `each` table.